Rust library for in memory times series data cache
I am looking for an open source Rust library for an in memory time series data cache. I am aware of time series data servers, such as InfluxDB and Redis Time Series.

But I am looking for code that can be compiled into or dynamically linked with an application.
That is, I am not looking for a central server; each instance of the application should have its own instance of the cache.
The priority is to have the cache stored in memory, but an optional disk store would be a bonus.
Each request to get data from the cache would contain a time range and list of one or more unique data source identifiers.
Each request to put data into the cache would contain one or more time series tagged with the time range and the unique source identifier.
Times need to be held as 64 bit or larger unsigned integers.
For each identifier in the request the cache should return what it has stored in the given time range and the list of time ranges that it does not have data for, if any.

If there is no existing library, recommendations for algorithms or papers that would help to write one would be welcome.
